# Can org-babel 'result' not insert a newline at the end?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I run a snippet of code (`C-c C-c`) (e.g. for making a PlantUML diagram), there is a trailing new line in the results, e.g.:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml file hello.png
...
#+END_SRC

#+results
[[img]
   <<<<<<< new line here :-|
```

I then have to manually delete that line as it messes with some of my header formatting.

**[edit]** 
As per comment below, I tried:

```
#+NAME: diagram123
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file ./img/img_2015_03_11__09_32_36.png
start 
:meh;
end
#+END_SRC


#+CALL: diagram123()
```

But this generates a result block with a new line at the end also :-|

Comment: See if you could work around it with `call_<name>([arguments])` syntax (explained here: http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html ).

Comment: I can't figure out what to do based on the link above? >_<, please advise.

Comment: You can add `#+NAME: diagram` before the code block, and then, where you want to insert the image: `call_diagram()`.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't quite get it working. I edited my question to show what I tried. Thoughts?

Comment: If you use `#+CALL: name` you don't need parenthesis after the `name`.

Comment: I edited the question. I tried without paranthases, but C-c C-c still tells me that I can't do anything useful at that location?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You do need parents, but you cannot have a white space between `CALL` and `:`.

Comment: Ok, I got that working, but it still gives me the new line at the end that messes with headings :-|

Comment: Both with the `#+CALL: diagram123()` and `call_diagram123()`? The second one is specifically made to insert results inline in the text.

Comment: The inline version kinda works, but then the images don't actually show with org-mode's inline images. Maybe I'm asking for something that's not doable?

Comment: What if you `C-c C-x C-v` (org-toggle-inline-images) after the diagram is created? (Maybe you'll need to do it twice).

Comment: well, it inserts the image in : =./img.png= format. I then would have to manually change it to [[./img.png]] before inline images work. Also every time I evalutate inline blocks (call_diagram123), an extra image is inserted but the old one is not removed.

Comment: You will need to add more arguments to `#+CALL:` then. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as example:

```
#+NAME: diagram123
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file ./img/img_2015_03_11__09_32_36.png
start 
:meh;
end
#+END_SRC

Some text call_diagram123() some more text.
```

Exporting this to LaTeX gives this:

```
Some text \texttt{./img/img\_2015\_03\_11\_\_09\_32\_36.png} some more text.
```

---

```
#+NAME: diagram123
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file ./img/img_2015_03_11__09_32_36.png
start 
:meh;
end
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: diagram123() :results file :exports results

#+RESULTS:
[[file:./img/img_2015_03_11__09_32_36.png]]
```

This is a way to export it to be a file link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm looking for something that will work in org-mode without exporting things..>?

Comment: Meh, this still inserts the trailing new line when results are evaluated. But in the mean time I figured out a way to deal with the trailing new line that messed with my headers in a different way. I appreciate your effort in posting the above. wvxvw << I've seen your name all over the place, you're a busy guy :-O

Comment: btw, maybe you know something in this post?: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/can-you-have-org-mode-headings-with-checkboxes